# Search and link to Entries Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, search, field, query

I'm trying to create somewhat of a clever search for which only searches through certain pages of my site. At the moment, it can search those pages, but instead of the result returning the page name, I want it to return a field within the matrix field which the search query can be found in.

As an example below, if a user were to search for ***Lorem Ipsum***, I want it to return the page name as well as the matrix field title.

> **This is my title**
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

Desired result:

> Page Name: This is my title

So far, the code I have can be found here, but I'm unsure how to access to exact matrix field title and add it to the query.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score').section(['pageOne', 'pageTwo', 'pageThree']) %}

{% if entries|length %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that title is a subfield of a matrix field, because title is a reserved name in craft. So as far as I understand your Question, you want to get some results out of a matrix field thats in one of your pages ('pageOne', 'pageTwo', 'pageThree'). That means you have to loop over this field as well.

```
{% if entries|length %}
   {% for entry in entries %}
       {% for block in entry.matrixFieldHandle %}
          <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }} - {{ block.matrixTitle }}</a>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: Your Welcome. I just realized, that title is also forbidden inside a matrix field, so i changed the handle inside the block to 'pageName' ;)

Comment: What you had was perfect, {{ block.title }} was what gave me the field title. just needed both {{ entry.title }} - {{ block.title }} for page name and field name :)

Comment: @Amy I'm just curious: how were you able to insert `title` as a field handle in your craft matrix field? `title` is a reserved keyword it's usually not possible to use it as a handle

Comment: The section I was looking to search through was a Q&A section, so my title was {{ entry.question }}. You are right, you cannot use just 'title', bad example on my part